# using Result<> without a type in F#

Tags: f#

I would like to do something like this:

```
let a x : Result<_, string> =
    match x with
    | 1 -> Ok
    | _ -> Error "not 1"
```

this will not compile.

Is there a way to not specify an ok type and return nothing?

Comment: You can use `Ok ()` but consider also using an option, something like `let error = if x = 1 then None else Some "not 1"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an experienced F# coder, but my understanding is that the way of indicating "no return value" is to use a `Unit`.

This compiles. Would it suffice for what you're doing?

```
let a x =
    match x with
    | 1 -> Ok ()
    | _ -> Error "not 1"
```

Or with an explicit return type:

```
let a x : Result<Unit, string> =
    match x with
    | 1 -> Ok ()
    | _ -> Error "not 1"
```

Given that `Ok` is a parameterized type, I don't think there's a way to get `Ok` by itself to work for what you're doing.